# Change page refresh timer

Tags: javascript, php, html, refresh, page-refresh

I have a specific requirement where my page refreshes after 2 seconds. I have used this code to achieve this functionality -

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "2";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    </head>
</html>
```

Now I require a button which changes the refresh time from 2 to lets say 10 seconds for a different functionality.

It would be of great help if someone suggests how I should achieve this. Thankyou

Answer (score 0):

add button with js code:
in HTML

```
<button onclick="fnc()">Button</button>
```

add tag ID in meta

```
<meta id="ref" http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
```

add js script into your page

```
<script>
  function fnc() {
    const d = document.getElementById('ref')
    d.content = 10;
  }

</script>
```

UPD:
result page:

```
<?php
    $page = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
    $sec = "2";
?>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta id="ref" http-equiv="refresh" content="<?php echo $sec?>;URL='<?php echo $page?>'">
    <script>
        function fnc() {
        const d = document.getElementById('ref')
        d.content = 10;
        }    
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button onclick="fnc()">Button</button>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Sorry it didn't work

Comment: Can you show what you have done in your file? It works locally for me.
I updated my answer, added an approximate view of the returned page

Comment: I straight up copy pasted your result page code in a new page. Still doesn't work

Comment: What exactly is not working? No button? When you click on the button, does the page reload time change? Or maybe after a reboot, the time goes back to 2 seconds?

Comment: After clicking the button the page refresh time doesn't change

Comment: Show how you applied the recommendation.
At me locally at pushing the button, the timer changes.
But after refreshing the page, of course, the settings are returned.